# MySQL Insert Data into Table1 when a matching record is found in Table2

Tags: mysql, database, merge

I have two tables data1 and data2.
Data1 contains contains 2 columns, emailaddress and name, but the name column is empty.

```
emailaddress    name
email1
email2
email3
```

Data2 Contains also contains 2 columns, emailaddress and name, and has more entries than data1

```
email address   name
email1          name1
email1b         name1b
email2          name2
email2b         name2b
email3          name3
email3b         name3b
```

I'm trying to write an SQL query that compares the email address column from Data1 and Data2, and when it finds a match, the associated name from Data2 is inserted into the corresponding name field for data1.

Data1 would should look like this after the query has been run

```
emailaddress    name
email1          name1
email2          name2
email3          name3
```

I just can't seem to figure out how to do this. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
UPDATE data1 a, Data2 b
SET a.name= b.name
WHERE a.emailaddress = b.emailaddress
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was about to type.

Comment: @nolt2232
PERFECT! This worked out great. Thank you for your help.
One last thing though, what exactly does 'a' and 'b' do? Are these variables?

Comment: They are just aliases for the table names. Just a shortcut so you can type "a" instead of having to type "Data1" everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

try this

this only Displays the result of the joined table.

```
SELECT a.emailaddress,
       b.name
FROM   Data1 a INNER JOIN Data2 b 
               ON a.EmailAddress = b.emailaddress
```

**UPDATE**

this query updates Data1 table.

```
    UPDATE a 
    SET  a.name = b.name
    FROM Data1 a INNER JOIN Data2 b 
               ON a.EmailAddress = b.emailaddress
```